# Boxplot with groupby two features

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

Say I have a df consisting of 3 columns ['Y/N','Test Before','Test After'], where 'Y/N' is boolean and 'Test Before,' 'Test After' is float.

eg,

```
'Y/N'    'Test Before'    'Test After'
True         75               100
False        75                50
True         50                60
False        50                40
  ...
```

I can use `df.boxplot(column='Test Before/Test After', by 'Y/N')` to create separate boxplots of 'column name' each grouped by 'Y/N.'

However,  I would like to create separate boxplots of boolean 'Y/N,' grouped by 'Test Before,' 'Test After,' eg:

Boxplot A contains boxplots of df['Y/N'] == True for x values df['Test Before'] and df['Test After'].

Boxplot B contains boxplots of df['Y/N'] == False for x values df['Test Before'] and df['Test After'].

Comment: Not sure what you mean, and I'm not sure that makes sense.   Clearly I can extract series using groupby and then plot the separate series....

Answer (score 1):

While your desired result is a bit unclear, consider [melting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) your data before plotting to have one indicator column for *Test Stage* and one value column for *Test Value*. Then plot with seaborn's [boxplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) with *Y/N* as the legend (hue) series or with seaborn's [FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) with separate graphs for each *Y/N* distinct value. Below runs on seeded, random data for demonstration:

**Data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(11012018)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Y/N': np.random.choice([True, False], 50),
                   'Test Before': [np.random.uniform()*10 for _ in range(50)],
                   'Test After': [np.random.uniform()*10 for _ in range(50)]},
                  columns = ['Y/N', 'Test Before', 'Test After'])

# MELT DATA (WIDE TO LONG)
melt_df = df.melt(id_vars="Y/N", value_name="Test_Value", var_name="Test_Stage")
print(melt_df.head())
#      Y/N   Test_Stage  Test_Value
# 0  False  Test Before    7.573898
# 1   True  Test Before    3.487735
# 2  False  Test Before    1.506599
# 3  False  Test Before    9.833866
# 4   True  Test Before    1.340375
# 5  False  Test Before    3.678094
# 6   True  Test Before    3.407419
# 7  False  Test Before    0.427210
# 8  False  Test Before    6.988953
# 9  False  Test Before    2.912770
```

**Plot**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
sns.boxplot(data=melt_df, x='Test_Stage',  y='Test_Value', hue='Y/N', ax=ax)

plt.legend(loc='upper right')
```

[image: Single Box Plot]

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(melt_df, col="Y/N", height=4, aspect=6/4)
g.map(sns.boxplot, data=melt_df, x='Test_Stage',  y='Test_Value')
```

[image: Grid Box Plot]

**Additional Data**

Should there be more than just *Test_Before* and *Test_After* values, `melt` scales to it with *order* specifying box plots arrangement:

```
np.random.seed(11012018)
df['Test Middle'] = [np.random.uniform()*10 for _ in range(50)]
melt_df = df.melt(id_vars="Y/N", value_name="Test_Value", var_name="Test_Stage")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
sns.boxplot(data=melt_df, x='Test_Stage',  y='Test_Value', hue='Y/N', ax=ax,
            order=['Test Before', 'Test Middle', 'Test After'])
```

[image: Box Plot with Three Metrics]

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(melt_df, col="Y/N", height=4, aspect=6/4)
g.map(sns.boxplot, data=melt_df, x='Test_Stage',  y='Test_Value',
      order=['Test Before', 'Test Middle', 'Test After'])
```

[image: Grid Box Plot with Three Metrics]